# Getting the plot points for a kernel density estimate in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, kernel-density

I am using this code

```
kde = sns.kdeplot(x = data, fill = True, color = "black", alpha = 0.1)
```

to get the kde for my data, and it works well. I am now trying to get all the x,y - point used to draw the plot and I am doing:

```
poly = kde.collections[0]
x_values = poly.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0]
y_values = poly.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 1]
```

However, the x_values increase and then decrease. Why? I understand the y_values should increase and decrease, but I expect the x_values to be increasing since the curve is drawn from left to right. By the way, the values of the points is reasonable and matches the plot, except for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `fill=True`, a filled polygon is created. `ax.text()` can be used to show the index of each point of the circumference.  It seems first the points create the base of the polygon, and then go back following the upper part of the polygon.

The code below shows the order of every 10th point, and uses `ax`, as the name `kde` might be a bit confusing for a subplot.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

ax = sns.kdeplot(x=np.random.randn(200).cumsum(), fill=True, color="black", alpha=0.1)

poly = ax.collections[0]
x_values = poly.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0]
y_values = poly.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 1]

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x_values[::10], y_values[::10])):
    ax.text(x, y, i, ha='center', va='center', color='b')
```

[image: showing the index of the points of sns.kdeplot]

To get the points of just the curve, you could create the `kdeplot` with `fill=False`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(200).cumsum()
ax = sns.kdeplot(x=data, fill=True, color="black", alpha=0.1)
sns.kdeplot(x=data, fill=False, color="red", ax=ax) # temporarily draw a curve

x_values, y_values = ax.lines[0].get_data() # get the coordinates of the curve
ax.lines[0].remove()  # remove the curve again

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x_values[::10], y_values[::10])):
    ax.text(x, y, i, ha='center', va='center', color='b')
```

[image: sns.kdeplot with numbered points of the curve]

It's much safer to use the curve instead of the polygon, as its direction and starting point might differ in future versions. The very first point of the polygon is probably the first point of the curve (to "close" the polygon). The curve is never fully zero. You can use the `cut=` parameter to extend the curve further into the almost-zero region. Note that the kde is just an approximation of the pdf. Its fidelity depends on how much the underlying distribution locally looks like a gaussian.

Comment: So, it is creating a counterclockwise curve. So, if I want to get the integral of the area under the curve up to a certain x0, I will only take the second part of the curve and reverse the order, and then integrate to the point to get the area, correct? However, the other funny part is that the very first point is not on the base of the polygon because y is not zero (at least for me)